# How to make the Ticks mark for particular values of coordinate longer than other?

Tags: plotting, ticks

Consider the following plot:

```
TicksPloty = 
  SortBy[Join[
    Flatten[Table[{i*10^-j, ""}, {i, 2, 9, 1}, {j, 3, 7, 1}], {1, 
      2}], {{10^-7, "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-7\)]\)"}, {10^-6,
       "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-6\)]\)"}, {10^-5, 
      "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-5\)]\)"}, {10^-4, 
      "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-4\)]\)"}, {10^-3, 
      "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-3\)]\)"}}], #[[1]] &];
TicksPlotx = 
  Join[Flatten[
    Table[{i*10^j, ""}, {i, 2, 9, 1}, {j, -3, 0, 1}], {1, 
     2}], {{10^-3, "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-3\)]\)"}, {10^-2, 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-2\)]\)"}, {10^-1, 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-1\)]\)"}, {1, 1}}];
LogLogPlot[10^-7/x, {x, 10^-3, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], 
 FrameTicks -> {{TicksPloty, None}, {TicksPlotx, None}}]
```

[image]

In this plot, all the ticks have the same length. I would like to make the ticks corresponding to coordinate $10^i, i = -7,-6,...,10$ longer than the other ticks. Could you please show how this may be done?

Update: To Daniel Huber.

[image]

Comment: In the [documentation for FrameTicks](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html) under "Properties and Relations" you find an example that begins with "Individually styled frame ticks can be used with other styles, and have higher priority". And under "Scope"/"FrameTicks Styling" there is an example that begins with "Specify the style of each frame tick". Maybe that can be used, I do not know.

Answer (score 4):

You may use the third agrument in a tick specification to specify its length:

```
TicksPloty = 
  SortBy[Join[
    Flatten[Table[{i*10^-j, ""}, {i, 2, 9, 1}, {j, 3, 7, 1}], {1, 
      2}], {{10^-7, "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-7\)]\)", 
      0.04}, {10^-6, "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-6\)]\)", 
      0.04}, {10^-5, "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-5\)]\)", 
      0.04}, {10^-4, "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-4\)]\)", 
      0.04}, {10^-3, "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-3\)]\)", 
      0.04}}], #[[1]] &];
TicksPlotx = 
  Join[Flatten[
    Table[{i*10^j, ""}, {i, 2, 9, 1}, {j, -3, 0, 1}], {1, 
     2}], {{10^-3, "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-3\)]\)", 
     0.04}, {10^-2, "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-2\)]\)", 
     0.04}, {10^-1, "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-1\)]\)", 
     0.04}, {1, 1, 0.04}}];
LogLogPlot[10^-7/x, {x, 10^-3, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], 
 FrameTicks -> {{TicksPloty, None}, {TicksPlotx, None}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! However, in my case, the ticks are two-sided (please see the update to my question). Do you know what may be a reason for this?

Comment: @JohnTaylor What do you mean by "in your case"? Do you get a different result from the one Daniel showed? Or do you mean that you want to achieve a different result? On Win10-64 and MMA 12.3.1 I get the same result Daniel showed.